# Add image in wpf listview with c#

Tags: c#, wpf, image, listview

I am a new user to c# and WPF and I have a problem to populate a `ListView` with text and image.

This is my wpf code:

```
  <Grid>
    <ListView Name="MyList" Margin="0,0,328.4,-0.2" >
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Rete" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Rete}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Immagine" >
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Image  Source="{Binding Immagine}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
        <Image Height="100" Width="100"/>
    </ListView>
    <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="324,83,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click"/>
     </Grid>
```

and this is my c# code:

```
while (r.Read())
        {

            MyList.Items.Add(new { Rete = r.GetString(0), Immagine = r.GetString(1) });
        }
```

**thanks to all i have solved!!! i changed the image path in the databse the code was correct!! :)**

Comment: Where is your problem? Reading data or displaying the data?

Comment: My problem is displaying data! the text is ok but i don't see the image. The image is in the debug folder and i read her name correctly!

Comment: Why on earth would you put an image in the `Debug` folder? It *should* be in a folder named `Images` for clarity surely? Also, please show us  the value(s) that you are using for the `Image.Source` in your `Immagine` property.

Comment: First, like @Sheridan said it shouldn't be in the `Debug` folder. you should have it in some `images` folder in your project hirarchy. Then make sure `Immagine` contains the absolute or relative path of the image, for example `"images\myimage.jpg"` and make sure that path is accessible from the executing code.

Comment: @Stefano on a side note, since you are new to C# and WPF I'd suggest you to learn [MVVM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) and not add items to the list directly.

Comment: yes is more clear but it isn't the problem! :)

Comment: Please show us the value(s) that you are using for the `Image.Source` in your `Immagine` property.

Comment: the value of the Immagine is ImageNotFound.jpg i put this in the debug folder for avoid to construct the incorrect path to image.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is my xaml code.

```
  <Grid>
    <ListView x:Name="ListView1"   VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" Height="200"  ItemsSource="{Binding ListViewItemsCollections}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="False">
                <GridViewColumn x:Name="GridViewColumnName" Header="Name"  Width="200">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Image x:Name="Image_GridViewColumnName" Width="100" Height="50" Source="{Binding GridViewColumnName_ImageSource}" />
                                <Label Content="{Binding GridViewColumnName_LabelContent}" Width="50" Height="100"  />
                                <Label Content="{Binding GridViewColumnName_ID}" Visibility="Hidden" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn x:Name="GridViewColumnTags" Header="Tags" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding GridViewColumnTags}" />
                <GridViewColumn x:Name="GridViewColumnLocation" Header="Location" Width="238" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding GridViewColumnLocation}" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

This is my c# part..

```
 public ObservableCollection<ListViewItemsData> ListViewItemsCollections { get { return _ListViewItemsCollections; } }
    ObservableCollection<ListViewItemsData> _ListViewItemsCollections = new ObservableCollection<ListViewItemsData>();

    public MainWindow()
    {

        InitializeComponent();

        ListViewItemsCollections.Add(new ListViewItemsData()
        {
            GridViewColumnName_ImageSource = @"D:\rd\C Sharp\general\StackOverFlowAnswers\WPF\MSD.JPG",
            GridViewColumnName_LabelContent = "shanmugharaj"
        });

        ListView1.ItemsSource = ListViewItemsCollections;
    }

    public class ListViewItemsData
    {
        public string GridViewColumnName_ImageSource { get; set; }
        public string GridViewColumnName_LabelContent { get; set; }
        public string GridViewColumnName_ID { get; set; }
        public string GridViewColumnTags { get; set; }
        public string GridViewColumnLocation { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I tested with these its working fine..
If my understanding id right this is you need..